# End If without Block if - Indented, but still doesn't work

Tags: vba

I constantly get the error "End If without Block If" although I have an End if for the beginning If and also tried indenting the statement. What is wrong?

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then

    MsgBox "Please Enter Value"

Else:
    Sheets("confirmation").Range("F7").Value = ComboBox1.Value
    Sheets("confirmation").Range("F9").Value = TextBox1.Value

    For i = 20 To 1 Step -1
        Rows(i & ":33").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Cells(13 + i, 1).Value = 20
        i = i + 1
    Exit For
    UserForm1.Hide
End If
```

Comment: `tried indenting the statement` indentation (unlike in python for example) has no influence in vba.
Search for "vba syntax" if you need more information.

Comment: Beware! That “i = i + 1” inside a “For i = 20 To 1 Step -1” loop results in an infinite loop!

Answer (score 4):

Remove the colon after `Else`.

Replace `Exit For` with `Next`. With `Exit For` you can exit the For loop prematurely.

As @Bill Hileman mentioned in the comments, the For loop will run infinite because `i` is incremented within the loop, but is decremented in the For loop body.

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then

    MsgBox "Please Enter Value"

Else
    Sheets("confirmation").Range("F7").Value = ComboBox1.Value
    Sheets("confirmation").Range("F9").Value = TextBox1.Value

    For i = 20 To 1 Step -1
        Rows(i & ":33").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Cells(13 + i, 1).Value = 20
        i = i + 1
    Next
    UserForm1.Hide
End If
```

Comment: For for/next loop counts backwards, but inside the loop i is incremented.  It will never exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need also to indicate where the for loop ends, with `next`. And you need to remove the `:`

```
If ... Then
  ....
Else

  For ...
    ...
    Exit For
  Next

End if
```